# Como mudar a cor do texto fora de uma função Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Estou tentando mudar a cor de um texto fora de uma função com Tkinter. Já tentei colocar o Label dentro da função mas fica sobrescrevendo um texto sobre o outro.
Segue o código.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter as tk

var_35='black'
fg1='black'

master = Tk()
master.geometry('850x700')
master.title('Vias Size')


w = Canvas(master, width=600, height=400, bg='white')
w.grid(row=20,column=0, columnspan=10)



def Solve():
    global fg1
    wth = int(cth.get())
    fg1='black'
    ring = "Ring size = %d µm" % (wth)
    if wth>120:
        fg1 = 'orange'
        print (fg1)
        var12.set(ring)
    elif wth>80:
        fg1= 'red'
        print (fg1)
        var12.set(ring)
    else:
        print (fg1)
        var12.set(ring)


var_1=StringVar()
Label_10 = Label(master, textvariable = var_1,font=('Arial',15),padx=5).grid(row=1,column=0, columnspan=5)

var12=StringVar()
print(fg1)
Label_12 = tk.Label(master, textvariable=var12, font=('Arial',12),padx=5, fg=fg1, bg='white').place(x=80, y=440)


Button(master, text='Solve',font=('Arial',14), command=Solve).grid(row=10,column=7, columnspan=1)

cth = ttk.Combobox(master, values=('25','35', '50','100', '150', '200'),font=('Arial',12) ,width=8)
cth.current(0)
cth.grid(row=6,column=3, columnspan=1)

mainloop()
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Bom primeiro temos que resolver um problema no código acima...
Você atribuiu a variável Label_12 a instancia de um Label já com o place, isso impossibilita você a trabalhar com as propriedades do Label, então primeiro você instancia o Label e depois realiza o place

```
    Label_12 = tk.Label(master, textvariable=var12, font=('Arial',12),padx=5, fg=fg1, bg='white')
    Label_12.place(x=80, y=440)
```

Agora dentro da função aplique o seguinte comando:

```
    **Label_12['foreground'] = fg1**
```

Assim você altera a cor de acordo com o parâmetro da função....

o seu código ficaria assim:

#########################################################

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

#########################################################

Uma outra dica, evite usar variável global, isso pode te causar alguns problemas para você, aplique a variável como parâmetro da função, ficaria melhor

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Olá, obrigado pela resposta, já estava achando que isso não era possível. Então, eu deixei a fg1 como global para testar se iria levar o valor da cor para o Label mas não havia resolvido, vou deixar a variável dentro da função. Obrigado mais uma vez.
abs

Comment: Opa, imagina
;)